# Trying to drop 13.5 volts to 10 volts in a car

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

Hi I am in no way an expert or even a mid novice when it comes to electronics so please forgive my ignorance. What I would like to do is in a car drop a 13.5 volt supply from an alternator to a 10 volt supply as a sender instruction to a power steering pump. I am just looking for what resistor / capacitor I would need to achieve this.

Comment: Do you know the current this pump will need? Why are you dropping to 10V? Why not 12? or 9? Where is the 13.5V supply from? How much current can it supply? How accurate does the 10V need to be? There is a lot of missing information in here. Could you please edit the question and provide specifications

Comment: The voltage you will get from a car will vary a lot, easily swinging from 10 to 14V, so you'll need proper regulating circuitry.

Comment: Capacitors aren't generally used to drop DC  voltages.  The alternator voltage isn't 13.5V.  It is nominally 13.5, but varies up and down from that by quite a bit.  What are you trying to do?  Do you need power for the pump?  That'd be one answer.  Do you need a control signal to the pump?  Entirely different answer.  There's lots of other cases, as well.  Almost none of them are answerable with "use this resistor value."

Comment: Sounds like you need a mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want '10v' then you need a regulator, a resistor/capacitor will not do.

However, you may not need 10v. If it's a signal to a car component, then the nominal 12v 'car voltage' will probably be accepted. Read the data sheet very carefully, or post a link to it so we can.

Answer (score -2):

Try [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/OOTDTY-DC-to-DC-4V-38V-to-1-25V-36V-5A-MAX-Step-Down-Power-Supply/32805601906.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.16.1ee91de7UjDrx8&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_5722815_10342_10325_10343_10546_10340_5722915_10548_10341_5722615_10696_10084_10083_10618_10304_10307_10820_5722715_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_5722515_10621_10620,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_7&algo_expid=3422bfb1-cf0d-4750-af3b-720184fb4f06-2&algo_pvid=3422bfb1-cf0d-4750-af3b-720184fb4f06&priceBeautifyAB=0) from aliexpress.com.